# TG BOT проблема с машиной состояний

Tags: python, многопоточность, aiogram

Пытался реализовать конструктор напоминалок по типу пользователь вводит команду /reminder записывает свое имя напоминалки и время и в боте просто таймер запускается на данную напоминалку и в определенное время отправляет ему , попробовал реализовать это с помощью FSM, бот сам написан на aiogram.
Вот код:

```
import datetime
import threading
from aiogram import Bot
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from core.utils.stepsreminder import StepsReminder


async def reminder_message(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer(f'{message.from_user.first_name}, введи название своего напоминания:')
    await state.set_state(StepsReminder.GET_NAME_REMINDER)


async def get_reminder_name(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer(f'Твоё название напоминания - {message.text}\r\nТеперь введи дату и время когда вы хотите'
                         f' получить напоминание в формате HH:MM')
    await state.update_data(reminder_name=message.text)
    await state.set_state(StepsReminder.GET_TIME_REMINDER)


async def get_reminder_time(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer(f'Твое время: {message.text}')
    await state.update_data(reminder_time=message.text)
    await state.set_state(StepsReminder.START_REMINDER)


async def start_reminder(message: Message, bot: Bot, state: FSMContext):
    context_data = await state.get_data()
    user_data = {message.chat.id: {'reminder_name': context_data['reminder_name']}}
    try:
        reminder_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(context_data['reminder_time'], '%HH:%MM')
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        delta = reminder_time - now
        if delta.total_seconds() <= 0:
            await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы ввели прошедшую дату, попробуйте еще раз!')
        else:
            reminder_name = user_data[message.chat.id]['reminder_name']
            await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напоминание "{}" установлено на {}'.format(reminder_name,
                                                                                                reminder_time))
            reminder_timer = threading.Timer(delta.total_seconds(), send_reminder, [message.chat.id, reminder_name])
            reminder_timer.start()
            await state.update_data(reminder_timer=reminder_timer)
            await state.set_state(StepsReminder.SEND_REMINDER)
    except ValueError:
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы ввели неверный формат времени , попробуйте еще раз!')


async def send_reminder(message: Message, bot: Bot, state: FSMContext):
    context_data = await state.get_data()
    reminder_name = context_data['reminder_name']
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Время получить ваше напоминание "{}"!'.format(reminder_name))
    await state.clear()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). начните с заголовка.